# How can you keep a record of notifications?

Tags: 10.10, notify-osd

I'm using Radio-Tray and I would like to keep a list of the tracks which get played and I was wondering if it was possible to do this by keeping a record of the Ubuntu notifications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the NotifyOSD logs from `~/.cache/notify-osd.log` and extract your data. Note that the log is cleared at each login.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Recent Notifications](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/never-miss-notifyosd-notification-with.html) GNOME applet. Besides keeping a log of your notifications, you can also copy links or text by right clicking them (useful for Twitter apps) and ban applications from being tracked.